# Wordpress visual editor losing formatting on copy/paste

Tags: wordpress, formatting, tinymce, copy-paste

I've just realized that **Wordpress Visual Editor** have a bug with **Internet Explorer 10 and below**. 
When I copy/paste a formatted text (eg with bold) from Word or a web page inside the content (Visual Editor) of my article, all my formatting automatically disappear (just after pasting the new text) wherever I paste the text...

Do someone know how to fix this problem ?

I know I can change my browser or update my IE, but my client could not at this moment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just found the solution!
It's due to my editor stylesheet `add_editor_style( 'css/editor-style.css' );`

Inside of it, I haved

```
body {
    ...
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

When I remove the font-weight from body, this resolve the bug.